# What compression utilities come with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, compression

I want to collect compression methods what are in the "default" Ubuntu 11.04 repository. I just trying to collect 1 plus thing: the parameter to set it to max compression, e.g.:

```
xz -9 FILENAME.tar
```

So: COMPRESSION-APP PARAMETER-TO-USE-MAX-COMPR PARAMETER-TO-GIVE-FILENAME

Can someone help me collect all the other ones? It's for comparing compression times and efficientlys.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Even if Ubuntu doesn't 'come with' some compression utilities, it's a simple matter to install any missing ones using the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of "default" compression utilities.  I'm not sure what you're doing, but I'll bet you don't need most of them.  Just pick the ones you need, and read the man pages for them.  If you want to see which are available, open up aptitude, or your favorite package manager, and search for the word 'compress'.  Then install them, and read their man pages.